# corba services clustering

Tags: load-balancing, corba

i am currently working on a SOA platform which is using corba.
i will try to cluster some services to a node and i need to design an architecture for this reason but i am new to this area and i cant think of a road map.
can you kindly give some tips to find my way  because i dont know where to look

also i have checked **"clustering", "load balancing", "high availability"** issues which i think i should pay attention and can not understand clearly .some berief explanation would be great
warm regards

Comment: Please tag more carefully. This is not [tag:cluster-analysis].